# How do I take care of my very small Kaffir lime tree?

Tags: trees, houseplants, tree-care, citrus

What is the general care of [Kaffir lime (*Citrus hystrix*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaffir_lime) trees? I have a very small tree that I'm growing as a houseplant.  How do I care for it?  Does it need a bigger pot?

Comment: In general, the correct size of the pot depends on the size of the plant. Please post a photo of your tree in its pot so we can get an idea of how big they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just ordered my Kaffir Lime tree.  It is so critical you put it in the proper sized pot.  Is it a 'sleeve' plant?  So a 1 or 2 gallon pot would be fine for quite awhile. I will be transplanting my plant or at least changing the soil once per year.  Upgrading the size if I see roots beginning to encircle the outside of the soil around the pot whenever necessary. DO NOT plant in a pot that is too big.

I'll be getting great potting soil that includes bacteria and mychorrhizae fungi.  No gravel at the bottom of the pot!  This actually causes the soil to become too wet! Make sure the bottom of the pot has airspace between whatever it is sitting upon.  Rocks, pavers or 'pot feet' will work fine.  If you use a saucer, dump out excess water.

I take all my indoor plants outside under a covering during the summer so they can get better light than what they could get in a home.  A great grow light really helps and is totally necessary if they have to remain indoors. Being able to grow outside during warm weather helps them gather enough energy to remain healthy through the winter.  They will die if a single cold snap happens, however.

Do you cook Thai?

Because they are in pots it is up to you to give them everything they need and it should be the best...soil; sterilized potting soil, not garden soil. No tap water unless you are on a well and you don't use salts for softening.  Drainage.  Careful with fertilizer, use organic slow-release and decomposed organic mulch.  Too little is better than too much. Light is critical.